# Display multiple result array

Tags: java, android

So far, I got my app working already, but I'm now faced with an issue. FYI, my app is about getting a user input (the user types in some sentence and app will look for ambiguous word/s and display its meanings).

**This is the code I have:**

```
final String[] words = {"cowboy", "animal" , "monster", "duck"};
final String[] meanings = { "meaning1", "meaning2", "meaning3", "meaning4" };

private void initControls() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
text = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);

view = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);

clear = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button2);

clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        text.setText("");
        view.setText("");
    }
});

ok = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button1);
ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        findAmbiguousWord();
    }   
});
}

private void findAmbiguousWord(){
String string = text.getText().toString();

int index = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (string.toLowerCase().contains(words[i].toLowerCase())) {
        check = true;
        index = i;
    } 
}

view.setText(check ? meanings[index] : "No ambiguous word/s found.");
}
```

But whenever I type a sentence like:

```
 My friend is a cowboy. He is also fond of duck.
```

It only displays the first word i.e. **COWBOY**. How do I display the other words? Help is much needed and appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to use collections.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add results in a collection, for instance a `Set` or a `List`:

```
private void findAmbiguousWord(){
String string = text.getText().toString();
// create a set to store the results
Set<String> result = new HashSet<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (string.toLowerCase().contains(words[i].toLowerCase())) {
        // ambiguous word, we need its meaning!
        result.add(meanings[i]);
    } 
}

// display the results if there are some
view.setText(result.isEmpty() ? "No ambiguous word/s found." : result.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, care to explain the code? And also how do I remove the brackets?

Comment: The bracket are added by HashSet.toString() method. You can customize the string by iterating on the set objects and create it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list of indices or build your output-String in the loop instead of storing only one index.

Answer (score 0):

```
 StringBuilder ambiguousWords = new StringBuilder();
 for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (string.toLowerCase().contains(words[i].toLowerCase())) {
        check = true;
        ambiguousWords.append(meanings[i]);
    } 
 }

 view.setText(check ? "No ambiguous word/s found." : ambiguousWords.toString());
```

Comment: What will be the use of StringBuilder in here?

Comment: To build a String. The String being the meanings of the ambiguous words. Clearly you could do something nicer like append(words[i] + ":" + meanings[i] + "\n");